# Yii2 transfer logic from view to model

Tags: yii2

I would like to arrange my code a little bit better. I have this in view, generated by giiant:

```
$form->field($model, 'land_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name'), [
                'prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select'),
                'disabled' => (isset($relAttributes) && isset($relAttributes['land_id'])),]);
```

Somebody has told me here on stackoverflow that it's not really nice. So I would like to transfer this part:

```
ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name'
```

into model. The same applies to grid filter dropdowns:

```
'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\base\Land::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
```

Does it make sense? I think so, I hope so. I've tried to implement it in model Land 2 ways:

```
public function getAllAsArray() {
    return ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');
}
```

or

```
public function getAllAsArray() {
    return ArrayHelper::map($this->find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');
}
```

and I wanted to call it from View/Grid (Zip - Land):

```
'filter' => $model->land->allAsArray,
```

but I'm getting the following error:
Undefined variable: model

then tried this way:

```
'filter' => function ($model) {$model->getLand()->one()->getAllAsArray();},
'filter' => function ($model) {$model->getLand()->getAllAsArray();},
```

then I get no error messages, but it's also not working.

and in Form (Zip - Land) the same way:

```
$form->field($model, 'land_id')->dropDownList($model->land->allAsArray(), [
            'prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select'),
            'disabled' => (isset($relAttributes) && isset($relAttributes['land_id'])),]);
```

but I'm getting the following error:
Call to a member function getAllAsArray() on null

Can you please point me to the right direction? I think I don't understand something basically and this disturbes me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: no need to use relation call it like `Land::getAllAsArray()`.

Comment: if in index: `'filter' => Land::getAllAsArray(),` then: **Class 'Land' not found**. if: `'filter' => \app\models\base\Land::getAllAsArray(),` then: **Class 'app\models\base\app\models\Land' not found** (?!) it's strange. if I define path, it's too much, if not, it's not enough.

Comment: check your model path, i guess it should be `app\modules\base\models\Land` insted of `app\models\base\app\models\Land` if your class inside module. Add `use app\modules\base\models\Land;` on top of `index.php`.

Comment: nope, it's not inside a module.

Comment: seems to be working now. function must be in **models/Land**, not in _models/base/Land_. You were right in view I needed `use app\models\Land;`, and by dropdown instead of _dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name'), [_ it's now just **dropDownList(Land::getAllAsArray(), [**. seems much better now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: please answer it, so I can accept

Comment: one more detail, path was wrong defined in function. it must be `public static function getAllAsArray() {
        return ArrayHelper::map(Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');
    }`

Comment: but I would like to know how could it be implemented with ActiveQuery class (LandQuery) instead, because it should be rather there if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Land model**

```
public static function getAllAsArray() {
    return ArrayHelper::map(Land::find()->orderBy('name')->all(), 'id', 'name');
}
```

**index**

```
use app\models\Land;

'filter' => Land::getAllAsArray(),
```

**form**

```
use app\models\Land;

$form->field($model, 'land_id')->dropDownList(Land::getAllAsArray(), [
        'prompt' => Yii::t('app', 'Select'),
        'disabled' => (isset($relAttributes) && isset($relAttributes['land_id']))]);
```